# Generic Type Erasure Warning

Tags: java, generics

I have this code from the book **Thinking in Java**,where Bruce indicates the warning on calling the method **set()**. The code is as follows:

```
    package testPackage;

    class GenericBase<T> {
    private T element;
    public void set(T arg) { arg = element; }
    public T get() { return element; }
    }
    class Derived1<T> extends GenericBase<T> {}
    class Derived2 extends GenericBase {} // No warning
    // class Derived3 extends GenericBase<?> {}
    // Strange error:
    // unexpected type found : ?
    // required: class or interface without bounds
    public class ErasureAndInheritance {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Derived2 d2 = new Derived2();
        Object obj = d2.get();
        d2.set(obj); // Warning here!
        }
    }
```

If I remove the annotation, I get the following warning:
Type safety: The method set(Object) belongs to the raw type GenericBase. References to generic type GenericBase should be parameterized

My question is, Why is the warning displayed on the **set()** method? And can somebody please explain what this warning means?
Btw, I am completely new to Java Generics and although I read other questions on Generics, I am still somewhat confused on **Erasure**.

Comment: Erasure => After the compile process, the code doesn't know anything about the generics

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Well, that I understand but my confusion comes from mixing the raw and parametrized type.

Answer (score 3):

From the Java doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

> Generics were introduced to the Java language to provide tighter type
>   checks at compile time and to support generic programming. To
>   implement generics, the Java compiler applies type erasure to:
>
> - Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode,
>     therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.
> - Insert type casts if necessary to preserve type safety.
> - Generate bridge methods to preserve polymorphism in extended generic types.
> - Type erasure ensures that no new classes are created for parameterized types; consequently, generics incur no runtime overhead.

Simple: Every generic is a `Object` after the compile process, it just adds the casting for you, and if you did something wrong it will generate a compiler error.

About the `unchecked` annotation, it's used when the compiler can't be sure that what are you doing is correct (in fact, you use the raw type which is the same thing as `GenericBase<Object>`)

You have the warning since the `set` methods except the type `T` but since you are using a raw type, it don't know what `T` is, and generate this warning to let you know that you are using a raw type (bad thing).

You can use the annotations to say: "I know it's a raw type, but i know it's legal and i know what i'm doing".

Mixing raw types and generic types is possible due to the way that generics are implemented, as i said above, after the compiler process the `T` becomes `Object` and it means that a raw object like `GenericBase` is the same thing like `GenericBase<T>`.

The reason that it doesn't asks for any casting with generics, is because it will add the casts for you (and you can be sure that the code will always work in runtime without worry about a possible `ClassCastException`).

Comment: One thing I want to clarify is, when you say in the last paragraph about the automatic casting, do you mean that the reason for not getting a warning on the get() method(because of returning T) is the automatic handling of casting in this case?

Comment: In this case you don't have the warning because Derived2 contains Objects, and you save it in an Object. So there is no reason to generate a warning since no casting is needed at all

Comment: If I consider your reasoning, then in set() too, the receiving parameter will also be translated to an Object type, why does the warning appear then?(you know, an object is being passed while calling set() ) I mean the type identifier T gets translated to Object wherever T is present right?

Comment: Yes, after the compile it will be a Object but it will alters you because it could be something you don't want to do.